# Перестало отрабатывать получение файлов с google drive

Tags: google-drive

Используем запросы для получения файлов с диска, типа: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/file_id?alt=media&source=downloadUrl&access_token=xxx`

Запросы отправляются с одного сервера.

Но несколько дней назад в ответ на такие запросы стали получать

> We're sorry... ... but your computer or network may be sending
>   automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request
>   right now.

И ссылку на https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640

При этом поведение нашего сервиса не менялось, в консоли гугла в приложении через которое идут запросы нет никаких превышений лимитов, от гугла не было никаких предупреждений.

Подскажите, в какую сторону копать, где искать причину этого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно, это старый API.

Для v2 `downloadUrl` должен быть вида

```
https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/file_id?key=apiKey&alt=media&source=downloadUrl
```

Вы также должны в заголовках отдать токен

```
Authorization: 'Bearer ' + user_or_service_token
```

Не очень понимаю, зачем `key=apiKey` кроме статистики. На небольших проектах я его не использую.

Comment: сам УРЛ рабочий, для тех юзеров, которые у нас уже авторизованы были он работает, файлы они получают.

Comment: Может заблокировали как-то хитро?

Comment: А вот перенос токена из урла в заголовок помог. Спасибо!

Comment: @AndreyDobzhansky, спасибо. Буду знать.